# Getting Empty Output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Iam trying to Execute Dynamic Query, But Iam getting Empty Output.Where I'm Wrong?

```
SET @SQL=N'
SELECT GETDATE(),'+@AMUID+','+ @BNO + 
',LOT,BARCODEID,'+@ACTWT+',TARE_QUANTITY,''NA'',STAGE,0,0,0,
 '+ @UNAME+ ','+@PR + ',GETDATE()
  FROM DISPENSE_HOLD_START WHERE BATCH_NO='''+@BNO+''' AND BARCODEID='''+ 
  @BARID +'''  and IS_OUT=0';
 PRINT(@SQL)
```

Here `@AMUID,@BNO,@ACTWT etc` are Input Parameters Declared with `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data type.They are dynamic Iam getting nothing When I Print this.

Comment: You are printing your formed sql statement, not executing it.

Comment: Any NULL valued parameter ?

Comment: @PawanKumar nope

Comment: Anyone of your input parameter is NULL which is making the end string NULL and nothing getting printed.

Comment: You need to be using parameterized sql here, not just building up a string and executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case#1 :**

In your Above Query, You are using `PRINT` instead of `EXEC`. So Make sure you are executing the Query in your actual Code

```
EXEC(@SQL)
```

**Case#2 :**

If you are executing this, there is a possibility that if any of the Parameter Value is `NULL`, then the entire String will become `NULL`

If you add any Value to `NULL` the Result will be `NULL`

```
SELECT
    'ABC',
    'ABC'+NULL
```

Gives Me this

[image]

So Use `ISNULL`

```
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT 
GETDATE(),
'+ISNULL(@AMUID,'')+','+ISNULL(@BNO,'')+',LOT,
BARCODEID,'+ISNULL(@ACTWT,'')+',TARE_QUANTITY,''NA'',STAGE,0,0,0,
 '+ISNULL(@UNAME,'')+','+ISNULL(@PR,'')+',GETDATE()
  FROM DISPENSE_HOLD_START 
  WHERE BATCH_NO='''+ISNULL(@BNO,'')+''' 
  AND BARCODEID='''+ISNULL(@BARID,'')+'''  
  and IS_OUT=0';
EXEC(@SQL);
```

**Case#3**

Looking at your Code, I think you don't need a Dynamic SQL here. Instead, you can directly go Like this

```
SELECT
    GETDATE(),
    @AMUID,
    @BNO,
    LOT,
    BARCODEID,
    @ACTWT,
    TARE_QUANTITY,
    'NA',
    STAGE,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    @UNAME,
    @PR,
    GETDATE()
    FROM DISPENSE_HOLD_START
       WHERE BATCH_NO = @BNO
          AND BARCODEID = @BARID
          AND IS_OUT = 0
```

Comment: Here I have to Insert Data into table where Table name is dynamic.But Iam not getting data in Select Itself So I Posted this

Comment: Then it is possible that your issue falls on Case#2

Answer (score 2):

as you are not executing the query but printing it 
this is same as 
3+3=6 and "3"+"3"="33"

the dynamic queries are typically executed like this(simplest method)

```
DECLARE @IntVariable int;  
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  

/* Build the SQL string one time.*/  
SET @SQLString =  
     N'SELECT BusinessEntityID, NationalIDNumber, JobTitle, LoginID  
       FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee   
       WHERE BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@BusinessEntityID tinyint';  
/* Execute the string with the first parameter value. */  
SET @IntVariable = 197;  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;  
/* Execute the same string with the second parameter value. */  
SET @IntVariable = 109;  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me

```
declare @val nvarchar(100) = 'tommy can you see me'
declare @SQL nvarchar(100) = N'SELECT GETDATE(), ''' + @val + '''';
PRINT(@SQL);
```